# why does REGEX GROUP treat list of strings sometimes as string and sometimes as list?

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I am parsing pdfs and extract text using regexes.

Here is a sample of `text_pos`

```
text_pos = [['5. qwe', 'LLL LLL  23', 'zzz qqq ewq (qwe ewq)', 'ewq \nqwe', 'eee  wwww', 'qwewww'],
            ['LLL LLL  54', 'ttt qqq (eee www)', 'eeee\neee', 'aaaaa \nwww'],
            ['K K K K K K   K K K K K K K   7 /', '111', 'zzz qqq qwe (ewq Lee)', 'qwee\neen', 'eewwww']]
```

Here is a **snippet of my code**

```
    text_pos = []
    .
    .
    .

    # REGEX
    aaa = re.compile(r'(K\s+K\s+K\s+K\s+K\s+K\s+K\s+K\s+K\s+K\s+K\s+K\s+K\s+\d.*)(zzz|ttt)', flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    bbb = re.compile(r'(LLL\s+LLL)(.*)(zzz|ttt)', flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    ccc = re.compile(r'(zzz|ttt\s+qqq)\s+(.*\))', flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    number = aaa.search(str(text_pos))
    number1 = bbb.search(str(text_pos))
    asker = ccc.search(str(text_pos))
    try:
        if number:
            number.group(0)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        if number1:
            number = number1.group(2)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        if asker:
            asker.group(1)
    except:
        pass
    
    data.append([number, asker])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =['text', 'number'])
```

the regex somehwat work but sometimes it seems to treat `text_pos` as string while sometimes not (returning only `re.Match object` instead of actual characters).

**Desired output:**

```
for v in df1['number']:
    print(v)

23
54
7 /111
```

---

```
for v in df1['asker']:
    print(v)

qqq ewq (qwe ewq)
qqq (eee www)
qqq qwe (ewq Lee)
```

**Actual output:**

```
for v in df1['number']:
    print(v)

23', 'zzz qqq ewq (qwe ewq)', 'ewq \nqwe', 'eee  wwww', 'qwewww'
54', 'ttt qqq (eee www)', 'eeee\neee', 'aaaaa \nwww
<re.Match object; span=(2, 3470), match="K K K K K K   K K K K K K K   7 /', '111', 'zzz >
```

---

```
for v in df1['asker']:
    print(v)

<re.Match object; span=(0, 59), match="['5. qwe', 'LLL LLL  23', 'zzz qqq>
<re.Match object; span=(24, 2203), match='ttt qqq (eee www)\', \'qwe>
<re.Match object; span=(47, 3015), match="zzz qqq qwe (ewq Lee)', 'q>
```

EDIT following Wiktors suggestion: tried to regex against each string in each list

```
for i in text_pos:
    for j in i:
        m = re.search(aaa, j)
        if m:
            number = m.group(0)
```

returns

```
for v in df1['number']:
    print(v)

<re.Match object; span=(2, 3470), match="K K K K K K   K K K K K K K   7 /', '111', 'zzz >
<re.Match object; span=(2, 3470), match="K K K K K K   K K K K K K K   7 /', '111', 'zzz >
<re.Match object; span=(2, 3470), match="K K K K K K   K K K K K K K   7 /', '111', 'zzz >
```

Comment: Regex only works on strings, never on objects.

Comment: I thought `.search(str(text_pos))` should make it treat like strings.. which seems to work for the first 2 list items

Comment: `text_pos` is a list of lists. When you cast it to string, it becomes a "clumsy" list-like looking string. This is not how you run regexps on string lists. You need to run the regex against each string in each list.

Comment: Sorry, I decided to have a closer look, and do not understand where your `df1['number']` is declared. Also, what is the problem now? Just getting the text of a match? Return `m.group()` and not just `m` (the result of `re.search`).

Comment: I edited the code so that you see df1 declaration. I am afraid if i understand your last sentence correctly, i do return number = m.group(0), which only returns re.match object for third list item.. i tried same with flattened list `text_pos = ' '.join(map(str, text_pos))` didnt help either. My problem is that i dont understand why it is returning the acutal text for the first two list items but not the third.

Comment: Look: `number = aaa.search(str(text_pos))` and `asker = ccc.search(str(text_pos))`, and then `data.append([number, asker])` and `df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =['text', 'number'])` lead to displaying match data object  rather than whole match values.

Comment: i dont know why your comment was helpful, but it was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot explain why the following works, but it does

```
    text_list = ' '.join(map(str, text_pos))
  
    aaa = re.compile(r'(K\s+K\s+K\s+K\s+K\s+K\s+K\s+K\s+K\s+K\s+K\s+K\s+K)(([^zzz|ttt]*).*)', flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    ccc = re.compile(r'(LLL\s+LLL)(([^zzz|ttt]*).*)', flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    
    number = aaa.search(text_list)
    number1 = ccc.search(text_list)
    
    if number:
        number = number.group(3)
    else:
        number = number1.group(3)

data.append([text_list, number])
fake_file_handle.close()

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =['text_list', 'WP / number'])


for v in df1['number']:
    print(v)

23
54
7 / 1864
```

Comment: You access the group value here, `number.group(3)`. When appending in `data.append([text_list, number])`, your `number` is already a string, not an object.